# Count number of rows that have X in cell A or B or C

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I think looking at the photo is the easiest way to show what I need:

[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQE2c.png)

**How do I set up a single formula to count the number of kids who failed an exam section?**

What I've managed so far is to create an extra column and set up some nested IF statements:

[Extra Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAOpY.png)

Then I can tally that E column. However, I'm trying to figure this out with creating an extra column. I'm stumped. I assume there has to be some CountIF and a range in the formula at the start.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a rather complex formula:

```
=SUM(N(MMULT(N(B3:D10="Fail"),ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COLUMNS(B3:D10)))^0)>0))
```

[image]

If you want to shorten this and don't mind an array-entered variant:

```
=SUM(N(MMULT(N(B3:D10="Fail"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B3:D10)^0))>0))
```

Confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you want to learn why/how these formula's work I suggest you read through this [link](https://excelxor.com/2015/03/30/counting-rows-where-at-least-one-condition-is-met/)

**EDIT**

Another option would be to use `SUMPRODUCT` like so:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((B3:B10="Fail")+(C3:C10="Fail")+(D3:D10="Fail")>0))
```

Which would make the whole thing a bit more understandable perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

**This Array Formula will solve the issue:**

[image]

*Formula to Count `Fail` in Cell `F142`:*

```
{=SUM(--(MMULT(--($C$136:$E$141=$E$142),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C$136:$E$141)))>0))}
```

**N.B.**

- Formula in Cell `F142`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Criteria **Fail** in Cell `E142`, makes the Formula Dynamic.

---

- **MMULT** returns the Matrix product of two Array.
- `(--($C$136:$E$141=$E$142)`, generates a `TRUE/ FALSE` for every value in Range.
- The Double negative `--` coerces the `TRUE/FALSE` into `1` & `0` like this.

`{1,1,1;0,1,0;1,0,1;0,0,0;0,0,1;1,0,0}`

- `TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C$136:$E$141))`, is  tricky part of the Formula, where **COLUMN** is used to  generate numeric array of the right size.
- For Non-zero  with `>0` & again coerce `TRUE/ FALSE` into `1` and `0`gets final array inside **SUM**.

`=SUM({1;1;1;0;1;1})`, returns `5`.

*You may adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*